# How to manage user data

Tags: firebase, swiftui

I'm currently learning how to user Firebase and Firestore databases with SwiftUI.
I am wondering **what's the best way to organise and manage users data.**

I already made some research but i'm still really confused.

In my test project, i implemented Firebase Phone Auth successfully but my data management is a mess. I make the call to firebase in the Button Action on my Phone Input View and then redirect to my Verification View where i check if the user give me the good verification number in the button action as well.

I heard about Model, View, ViewController model and i'm trying to implement that.
That means, i need to have a User Struct with all user properties to read them in my whole app ?

I'm wondering where i can find good documentations on how to manage and store user data in my swift app. I'm really confused and i'm going in all directions, i need to focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store very basic user data, like their name and email, you can use the built in functions of FIRUser. Adding displayName and emailAddress can be done with Swift like this:

```
let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
changeRequest?.displayName = displayName
changeRequest?.commitChanges { (error) in
  // ...
}
```

and for email:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.updateEmail(to: email) { (error) in
  // ...
}
```

However, if you want to store custom user data specific to the function of your app, I advise to use Firestore, a database platform provided by Firebase.

Setup your app with Firestore using this tutorial:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

Once you have Firestore set up, you want to create a collection for your users, and each user will have a document with their data in, and this can be fetched using their UID.

When you create a user, you also want to create a doc in the user collection of your Firestore database, and when you want to access the user data, you want to read this data back.

For this a class that adheres to ObservableObject works well.

Make sure to import FirebaseFirestore and FirebaseAuth.

First create a custom struct to hold the values of our User. These are completely customisable and I am just including some examples. These can be highly sophisticated and specialised to your app's function.

```
struct CustomUser {
    var name: String
    var favouriteColor: String
    var dateCreated: Date
    var age: Int
}
```

Create a class like this

```
class UserFetch: ObservableObject {
    // ...
}
```

Then we want a variable that holds our user. To make sure that it is updated, we use the `@Published` property wrapper. Let's also add a variable that holds our Firestore collection for our users.

```
class UserFetch: ObservableObject {
    @Published var user: CustomUser?

    var collection: CollectionReference = Firestore.firestore().collection("users")
    // ...
}
```

Now we want to write a function that writes data to the document:

```
class UserFetch: ObservableObject {
    @Published var user: CustomUser?

    var collection: CollectionReference = Firestore.firestore().collection("users")

    func createUser(withName: String, favouriteColor: String, dateCreated: Date, age: Int, forUserID: String) {
        self.collection.document(forUserID).setData(["name": withName,
                                                     "favouriteColor": favouriteColor,
                                                     "dateCreated": dateCreated,
                                                     "age": age]) { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print((error?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            } else { print("CREATED DATA - USER: \(forUserID)") }
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

When you create a user, call this function.

Now we need to read the user from Firestore

```
class UserFetch: ObservableObject {
    @Published var user: CustomUser?

    var collection: CollectionReference = Firestore.firestore().collection("users")

    func createUser(withName: String, favouriteColor: String, dateCreated: Date, age: Int, forUserID: String) {
        self.collection.document(forUserID).setData(["name": withName,
                                                     "favouriteColor": favouriteColor,
                                                     "dateCreated": dateCreated,
                                                     "age": age]) { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print((error?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            } else { print("CREATED DATA - USER: \(forUserID)") }
        }
    }
    
    func fetch(uid: String) {
        self.collection.document("\(uid)").addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print((error?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            } else {
                print("READ USER DATA")
            }
        
            self.user = CustomUser(name: snapshot?.get("name") as? String ?? "", favouriteColor: snapshot?.get("favouriteColor") as? String ?? "", dateCreated: (snapshot?.get("dateCreated") as! Timestamp).dateValue(), age: snapshot?.get("age") as? Int ?? 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, add an initialiser that reads this data.

```
class UserFetch: ObservableObject {
    init(uid: String) {
        fetch(uid: uid)
    }
    @Published var user: CustomUser?

    var collection: CollectionReference = Firestore.firestore().collection("users")

    func createUser(withName: String, favouriteColor: String, dateCreated: Date, age: Int, forUserID: String) {
        self.collection.document(forUserID).setData(["name": withName,
                                                     "favouriteColor": favouriteColor,
                                                     "dateCreated": dateCreated,
                                                     "age": age]) { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print((error?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            } else { print("CREATED DATA - USER: \(forUserID)") }
        }
    }
    
    func fetch(uid: String) {
        self.collection.document("\(uid)").addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print((error?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            } else {
                print("READ USER DATA")
            }
        
            self.user = CustomUser(name: snapshot?.get("name") as? String ?? "", favouriteColor: snapshot?.get("favouriteColor") as? String ?? "", dateCreated: (snapshot?.get("dateCreated") as! Timestamp).dateValue(), age: snapshot?.get("age") as? Int ?? 0)
        }
    }
}
```